# Does SavedModelBundle loader support GCS path as export directory

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, tensorflow-serving

Currently I am using a saved_model file stored on my local disk to read an inference graph and use it in servers. Unfortunately giving a GCS path doesn't work for SavedModelBundle.load api.

Tried providing GCS path for the file but did not work.

Is this even supported, if not how can i achieve this using the SavedModelBundle api because i have some production servers running on google cloud that i want to serve some tensor-flow graphs.

Comment: I think this might be a bug. What language are you using, Java?

Comment: Also, have you considered using CloudML Engine's managed Online Prediction offering? https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/prediction-overview

Comment: I am using java . I cant use cloudML Engine because i am working on my own managed fleet of servers and have some SLA latency requirements. Also i don't believe  cloudML can handle the QPS i am trying to serve

Comment: Answered the question. Running your own instance of tensorflow_serving is certainly a reasonable thing to do in some cases. CloudML Engine (though still beta) aims to provide a managed serving so you have less work todo, I would love to hear your use case (latency, QPS, traffic shape) requirements. If you're willing to share those (even if you have no intention of using CloudML Engine), reach out to us privately at cloudml-feedback@google.com.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i actually opened a ticket internally as well and the answer i got was "The SavedModelBundle.load() function is not designed to work with GCS, it only allows the use of local folders. Tensorflow is not a library we support outside the context of Cloud ML. " Thanks for the info , i will try to use gcs path once its available in the latest release

Comment: The fix is pushed. When you say "internally" does that mean you work at Google? Or what system did you use to report? My guess is it was a cloud support representative who probably doesn't provide support for open source projects. The common support forums are github and SO, as you obviously know :)

Comment: oops sorry i used internally before when i was at google , but now i use google enterprise ticket , since we use GCP extensively

Comment: @ rhaertel80 I am currently using the 1.3.0 version , what release version should i use to be able to load models from gcs

Comment: Right now it's just @ HEAD; we'll try to push a patch release soon.

Answer (score 2):

A [recent commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/commit/f8cc9fd0d36ab6830340875d26aa7870369afe9e#diff-bf0c841686ee859a4e04283ff50ea0ac) inadvertently broke the ability to load files from GCS. This has been [fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/commit/c6ace3fed3a0ec7cec6b7267cd86b8ed3a034a50) and is available in github.